# Compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{5 + (-1)^n}{ \sqrt{n} +7}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute the limit : $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{5 + (-1)^n}{ \sqrt{n} +7}$

My work:

Since $(-1)^n$ can be either -1 or +1 so, with Sandwich Law the numerator can be within 4 and 6 i.e $$ 4 \leqslant 5 + (-1)^n \leqslant 6$$. The denominator grows accordingly with $\sqrt{n}$. Using this info how can I proceed further ?

Comment: You're almost there.  What's $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt n}$?

Comment: Great use of the Sandwich Law. Now you just need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}+7}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{6}{\sqrt{n}+7}$. If you have both of these, then the desired limit is "between" these values.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ohh thank you. the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is 0. I see it now.

Comment: I see that you deleted this question immediately after receiving an answer. That's unkind to those who took the time to answer your question and to others who come to MathSE looking for help in the future. It also makes it look like you're trying to hide something. **Don't do that.**

Comment: @davidlowryduda Sorry! Actually the problem was solved even before the answer, in the comments itself. Anyways, thank you for re-opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the inequality $4 \leqslant 5 + (-1)^n \leqslant 6$ by $\sqrt{n}+7$ to get that
$$
\frac{4}{\sqrt{n}+7}\leqslant \frac{5+(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+7}\leqslant\frac{6}{\sqrt{n}+7} \, .
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{4}{\sqrt{n}+7}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{6}{\sqrt{n}+7}=0 \tag{*}\label{*} \, ,
$$
by the sandwich theorem we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{5+(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+7}=0 \, .
$$
For a proof of $\eqref{*}$, we can show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}+7}=0
$$
for *any* constant $c$ using the formal definition of the limit. For every $\varepsilon>0$, if $\displaystyle{n>\max\left(100,\frac{|c|}{\varepsilon}\right)}$, then
$$
\left|\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}+7}\right|=\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{n}+7}<\frac{|c|}{n}<\varepsilon \, .
$$

Comment: Very nice answer. But have you choose $100$ to be sure? I not know because you have taken 100.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, I did it because it is clearly true that for $n>100$, we have $n>\sqrt{n}+7$. I don't think there is much worth in finding the *least* value of $n$ that works. Just like when writing $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs, we seldom look for the greatest value of $\delta$ that works. No point in being "economical".

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Sebastiano: No worries! Let me know if you have any more questions regarding my answer.

Comment: I can only give you fairly good advice on MathJaX or $\LaTeX$ in general. :-)

Answer (score 4):

My approach. Being

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5 + (-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+7}=\color{magenta}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{\sqrt{n} +7}}+\color{blue}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} +7}}$$
The sequence $(-1)^n$ is bounded. The product of a finite and an infinitesimal sequence gives a null limit. Hence the blue limit is $0$. The sequence is easy to solve because
$$\color{magenta}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{\sqrt{n} +7}}\equiv 0$$
Definitively:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5 + (-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+7}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{5}{ \sqrt{n} +7} =0
$$
and
$$
\left |\dfrac{(-1)^n}{ \sqrt{n} +7} \right | \leqslant \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{n} +7} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0
$$
so the limit is $0$.